# Where is the transform tool?

Tags: interface

I just installed Blender v2.8 but I can't seem to find any Transform tool.
Has it been removed or do I have to show it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it has. As explained in [April 15th's developer meeting notes](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/15-april-2019/6481):

> Transform gizmos can now be enabled in the 3D viewport independent of
>   active tools, from a popover menu in the header. The same popover also
>   has controls for display of other gizmos. The Transform tool was
>   removed as it is now redundant. (Campbell Barton)
>
> [image]