# Accidently Hid the Manipulator Widget(Move/Rotate/Scale)

Tags: 3d-manipulator

[image]I'm trying to familiarize myself with blender, and I touched something without looking at the keyboard, as one does, and the manipulator widget is now just missing from my screen. I've tried looking up how to re-enable it, but it points to something that I don't see on my interface.

So now I'm just stuck...

[image]

Comment: step 1:  click on the Item Tab (upper right on the 3d-view).  If all the "Location" text field lock are on, unlock them.   No widget will show otherwise, similar for Rotation, Scale, etc.

Comment: you probably disabled the [Gizmo for Active Tool](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137199/111042).  And from now on keep those hands off the keyboard and mouse!!!!  Welcome to the extremely arcane world of 3D editors... LOL

Comment: No, they're all unlocked, I don't know how it would've gotten locked otherwise.

Comment: Added a screenshot of that menu you linked and they're all on.

Comment: Edit :: Preferences :: Viewport :: Gizmo Size    ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I had the Animation Playback going, you can see it on the bottom part of the screen.

That turns off the Widget. I deleted that hotkey for now, don't need it at this moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

Ah!  "Touched something" like a shortcut key.

From the default hot-key-map file:

```
("wm.context_toggle",
 {"type": 'ACCENT_GRAVE', "value": 'PRESS', "ctrl": True},
 {"properties":
  [("data_path", 'space_data.show_gizmo'),
   ],
  },
 ),
```

translation: ctl-` (control back-quote)